# Get exact forms input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

There are 2 forms on my page. Lets say: their id's `form1`, `form2`. For ex. text input with `name="email"` exists in all 2 forms.

**How do I get the value of text input (named email) from exact form, lets say `form1`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
var email = $('#form1 input[name="email"]').val();
```

Based on your comment, if you wanted to localize the search for your input field for the `onsubmit` event, you could do this:

```
$("#signup_form").submit(function () { 
    var email = $('input[name="email"]', this).val();
});
```

The `$()` overload takes a container in which to limit the scope of the search; my example will only look for inputs with `name="email"` within `this` (the form).

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: If you're new to jQuery, I would suggest glossing through their [extensive documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Comment: One more Q. If I'm using this code inside submit func like `$("#signup_form").submit(function () {` should I use var email = $('this input[name="email"]').val(); instead?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you could do this

To get email field from #form1

```
$('[name="email"]' ,'#form1')
```

To get email field from #form2

```
$('[name="email"]' ,'#form2')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* have jQuery on your page (gasp!!), it's just as easy.

If you know that form1 comes first in the markup and form2 comes second:

```
var email1 = document.forms[0].email.value;
var email2 = document.forms[1].email.value;
```

If you don't know their order:

```
var email1 = document.getElementById("form1").email.value;
var email2 = document.getElementById("form2").email.value;
```